# How to mock integers in a class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I recently came across a situation where we inject an int, whose value is declared in a properties file.

```
@Inject
@ConfigurationParameter("someparameter")
private int resetCount;
```

How can I mock this variable/dependency. Is it possible?

For now I removed the `private` access specifier, and using the class's object I have set its value. But what if I want it to be declared private and still want to inject values or mock the variable?

Is injecting primary data types a good practice?

Comment: One way would be to use reflection...Having said that, i would try to maintain getter and setter as well for private fields.

Comment: This is one reason why injection via constructor is preferable - it makes it easier to test.

Comment: Yea, we also had the idea to use a setter method or reflection. But I don't think we are interested in that. Then I tried to use `Integer` class instead of datatype and mock the class. Then Mockito gave an exception that final classes cannot be mocked.

Comment: I'm not sure how replacing `int` with `Integer` would help in mocking. The best alternative is to inject this dependency through the constructor as suggested by @AlanStokes. Also you don't really need a mock/double for primitive data types.

Comment: There's never a reason to mock an int. It's a value type; just specify the value. As for how to specify the value, if it's final then use constructor injection; if it's not, you also have the option of adding a setter method.

Answer (score 1):

**ReflectionTestUtils** class provided by spring framework using this you can set any field of the class irrespective of its access modifier.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(yourClassName, "resetCount", 5);
```

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505567/mocking-private-field-of-a-class/22828451#22828451)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. There is a class called `WhiteBox` in `Mockito` api which can set the internal state of an object.

[Here is an example how it is done.](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox)